# a little code confuse me in this gem ---- backbone-bootstrap-rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, twitter-bootstrap-rails

in bootstrap.js.coffee ,there are some code:

```
define [], ->
  App =
    Models: {}
    Collections: {}
    Routers: {}
    Helpers: {}
    Views: {
      Posts: {}
      Common: {}
      Sessions: {}
      Tokens: {}
      Passwords: {}
      Confirmations: {}
    }
```

i dont understand why the "define" method is in the js code??
and more , in other code ,this "define" method uses everywhere!

assets/javascripts/models/post.js.coffee

```
define ['backbone', 'bootstrap'], (Backbone, App) ->
  class App.Models.Post extends Backbone.Model
    paramRoot: 'post'
    urlRoot: '/posts'

    defaults:
      title: null
      content: null
```

i want to know the method --- "define" , what do the method do , why i cant find where the method details to write??

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a JavaScript person, but I believe this is part of RequireJS.

According to [the docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defdep), it appears to be defining functions with dependencies:

> If the module has dependencies, the first argument should be an array
>   of dependency names, and the second argument should be a definition
>   function. The function will be called to define the module once all
>   dependencies have loaded. The function should return an object that
>   defines the module. The dependencies will be passed to the definition
>   function as function arguments, listed in the same order as the order
>   in the dependency array:

```
//my/shirt.js now has some dependencies, a cart and inventory
//module in the same directory as shirt.js
define(["./cart", "./inventory"], function(cart, inventory) {
        //return an object to define the "my/shirt" module.
        return {
            color: "blue",
            size: "large",
            addToCart: function() {
                inventory.decrement(this);
                cart.add(this);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

> In this example, a my/shirt module is created. It depends on my/cart
>   and my/inventory. On disk, the files are structured like this:
>
> - my/cart.js
> - my/inventory.js
> - my/shirt.js
>
> The function call above specifies two arguments, "cart" and
>   "inventory". These are the modules represented by the "./cart" and
>   "./inventory" module names.
>
> The function is not called until the my/cart and my/inventory modules
>   have been loaded, and the function receives the modules as the "cart"
>   and "inventory" arguments.
>
> Modules that define globals are explicitly discouraged, so that
>   multiple versions of a module can exist in a page at a time (see
>   Advanced Usage). Also, the order of the function arguments should
>   match the order of the dependencies.
>
> The return object from the function call defines the "my/shirt"
>   module. By defining modules in this way, "my/shirt" does not exist as
>   a global object.